# How to handle updating an animation from an IDrawable?

Tags: interface

I have two interfaces, IDrawable and IUpdateable.  Some concrete drawables are updateable, but not all.  A sprite with animations, for example, implements both IDrawable and IUpdateable but a static image just implements IDrawable.

The problem is obvious... how could I possibly update animations with just an IDrawable reference?  If I pass a Sprite to a Button to use as it's graphic representation, the Button just remains static because it can't advance it's sprite animations.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to define a new abstraction:

```
public interface IXXXObject {
   IDrawable Drawable { get; } // return null if not support IDrawable
   IUpdatable Updatable { get; } // return null if not support IUpdatable
}
```

All your objects should implement this interface.
Now you should pass objects as IXXXObject and you can call a feature if it is supporting.